# What happens to this thread runnable at the end once it is completed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I have this thread which downloads a few images from the server. So once it downloads the images I call the handler and carry on UI updation. So since stop() for thread is deprecated I am not able to use it. I have two questions here.

1. What happens to this thread in the end?(means after I call the handler method what happens to it).
2. OR how do I stop this thread without using stop()?

Here is my code.

```
handler=new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            if(msg.what==0)
            {
                //UI Updation takes place. 
            }
        }
    };



final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("Inside Thread", "Downloading Images...");
                     myDownlaodMethod();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thread will end and die on its own.  You don't have to end it yourself.  You won't be able to restart it without creating a new `Thread` object.  The garbage collector will handle whatever memory needs to be release.  The object will stay in memory as long as you hold a reference to it. Remove the reference, and the garbage collector will remove the object just like any other.

Comment: So what if in some case I want to stop this thread in the middle. How do i do it in android

Comment: If it had a permanent loop, you'd have to have a boolean condition like `while(a){// do everything }` and set `a` to false when you want it to die.  If your `myDownloadMethod()` has no way of being interrupted and canceled, then you'll have to create one or have a timeout to just let it die.  You're not supposed to just cut a thread in the middle of it's execution.  Best practice is to have it run to it's end.  Very often, you can use `Thread.interrupt()` for this purpose.

Comment: @DeeV check out the ExecutorService and Executors. Lots of thought when in to those guys and I have all to often seen developers reimplement what those classes do.

Comment: That looks like something that may be helpful for this.  It's probably what `AsyncTask` wraps around since it works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

If its the same as regular Java then it provides some powerful thread management including shutting down all the threads at once.

Comment: He is using Android, so AsyncTask is probably more appropriate then Executors.

Comment: Shutting down threads with `interrupt` as you suggest is not trivial since the threads have to be modified to correctly handle the interrupts.

Comment: @toto2 yes I agree. However Anything is better than just plain Thread. You should post an answer with AsyncTask (at the time I did not know about it).