# Android: Will a new thread simply stop after it has finished it's execution?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

**Will a thread simply terminate after it has completed its execution?**

This is how I initialize my thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        }
    }).start();
```

Basically what I am trying to do simply execute a single task on a new thread and then terminate the thread. However, after some time I will start another one and so forth. I don't want to have a bunch of threads started and I am wondering if the thread will terminate itself after complete ting it's execution?

Thanks.

Comment: Here ya go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037129/what-happens-to-this-thread-runnable-at-the-end-once-it-is-completed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. When `run` returns, the thread will stop.

To execute a single task in a thread on Android, you might want to consider using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. `AsyncTask` is designed exactly for this purpose. It gives you a simple way to pass data to the other thread, and pass progress updates and a final result back to the main thread. Each `AsyncTask` is like a `Thread`, but with those extra features.

Answer (score 5):

> Will a thread simply terminate after it has completed its execution?

Yes, It will terminate and exit itself after completing the `run()` method